# How does BI tools display large data say 100gb data on mobile?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, business-intelligence

I'm earger to know how does BI tools avaliable in market show large data on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way Wikipedia does. It only sends you the information you need when and as you need it.